# Losing data from Query to Excel sheet

Tags: excel, odata

I'm using Odata to get a connection to my API. No problem there, connection is working and my query gets the results I'm looking for in the preview UNTIL I click on **Close & Load** 
[image]

After clicking on this the result gets loaded into the Excel sheet (I can see this in FIDDLER) and there seems to be the problem as data is just disappearing. I get results for the whole last year from different customers, but some data is just getting lost while loading. There are months of missing data. There is no error in the query as the query is just going into an API endpoint.

So I assume there is something wrong in the settings, but I can't figure out where. 
If someone has any suggestions, I'm happy for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case, I saw in Fiddler that there was ONE Error arising at the beginning and then it started like everything was fine.
The problem was that there were unexpected input in one Column.
This fixed my issue:

```
#"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(Source, {{"Coumn4", null}})
```